# ORACLE: LISTAGG taking too long to output my results

Tags: python, oracle, listagg

Below is the SQL string I pass to a Oracle server via an Oracle API within Python. I suspect that the listagg function is the reason for the extended amount of processing time. Without the listagg function the results are parsed in under half the time that the below SQL takes. Any suggestions or fixes more than welcome.

```
SELECT to_char(a.transaction_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 
        a.sub_acct_nbr, 
        a.trn_ldgr_entr_desc, 
        a.fdoc_nbr, 
        a.fin_object_cd,
        a.fin_sub_obj_cd, 
        a.fin_obj_cd_nm, 
        b.explanation, 
        (select listagg(c.txt, ';') WITHIN GROUP (order by a.fdoc_nbr) from View3 c where a.fdoc_nbr = c.fdoc_nbr) Notes, 
        to_char(a.trn_ldgr_entr_amt, '9,999,999.99'), 
        a.trn_debit_crdt_cd
    FROM  View1 a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN View2 b
    ON  a.fdoc_nbr = b.doc_hdr_id
    WHERE   a.account_nbr = 123456
    AND     a.univ_fiscal_prd_cd = 12
    AND     (a.fin_object_cd BETWEEN '5000' AND '7999'
    OR      a.fin_object_cd BETWEEN '9902' AND '9905')
    ORDER BY a.transaction_dt;
```

Comment: Do you have an index on fdoc_nbr in Table1 and an index on fdoc_nbr in Table3? If not, create them and see if that helps.

Comment: Does "without the listagg" imply that you're removing the entire inline subquery so that you have no references to Table3 at all?  Or does that mean that you have the inline subquery with some other aggregate/ analytic function?  What is the query plan of these two queries and how long is "half the time" (are we dealing with added seconds or added milliseconds)?  Off the top of my head, I'd always prefer to have the analytic expression refer to columns from just one table so I'd do `order by c.fdoc_nbr` rather than `a.fdoc_nbr` when you're aggregating a column in `c`.

Comment: @JustinCave Yes, removing the entire inline subquery, in i.e., I do not use Table3. However, as a report my results are incomplete without the notes from c.txt (varchar2 800). The c.txt contains essential transaction information (text) that would make my report complete. Each fdoc_nbr has multiple notes appended to it and I am trying to collate multiple notes pertaining to a single fdoc_nbr into a single line item in my report. With the listagg function it takes 15 seconds on average and without it, the results are parsed in 8-10 seconds. I tried ordering by c.fdoc_nbr, still no difference.

Comment: @mathguy does ordering by c.fdoc_nbr (as mentioned by JustinCave obviate the need for indexing? If yes, I have tried it and yet no difference!

Comment: You'd still want appropriate indexes.  Using `c.fdoc_nbr` just ensures that Oracle can figure out that it can use a composite index on `fdoc_nbr, c.txt` for the aggregate without needing to transform your query.  The optimizer can probably manage that transform but I'd rather simplify things for the optimizer.  What are the query plans of the two queries?

Comment: No, whenever you need to "order by" a column, it helps if it's indexed. If you only order by the column in Table3, you only need the index in that table. But an index in both tables will help also with the join-like condition you have in that WHERE condition in the subquery.

Comment: @mathguy careful: 'whenever you need to "order by" a column, it helps if it's indexed" is an over-generalization.

Comment: @JustinCave speaking with my boss to get sufficient privileges for creating index and to view 'explain query plan'. Planning to create an index. Will update once I do this and hopefully I should also be able to get the query plan by then

Comment: @mathguy working on creating an index for both the tables